# How do I change gravity of box2d world after world is created?

Tags: c++, box2d

I want to modify the world of box2d after creating it, namely to change the gravity vector. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Seems like a simple documentation look up to me...

Answer (score 2):

`world.setGravity(b2Vec2(0.0, 0.0));`

Answer (score 0):

Or use `world.SetGravity(new b2Vec2(0.0, 10.0));`

Note the capital `S` and the `new` command.  It may depend on what version, language, etc. - not sure.

Comment: The question is tagged with c++ so there is no ambiguity here.